# Need to update table row from UDF in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I am using a function in the view for getting some result sets. In that function, based on some condition need to update rows to the database table.

Can anyone tell me, How can I do this

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do this using SQL Server. SQL Server does not allow Update/Delete/Insert statements in UDFs. I think you are also prevented from calling a stored procedure as well.

Comment: No work around. SQL Server does not allow functions to do Inserts/Updates/Deletes. You're going to have to do your data modifications within a stored procedure.

Answer (score -1):

SPs can read, write, delete, and update permanent tables.But you must be considerable if you wanna update rows in the base table (tables) of the view because there are some restrictions

Comment: @Balend - You didn't read the question closely. He wants to update rows inside a UDF. This isn't allowed by SQL Server.

Comment: I suggest possible solution to problem at general